# Error while exporting html test to Junit4 / Webdriver using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have following selenium IDE code when exported to JUnit 4 (Webdriver) returns an error.

Though It works fine when I export it as Selenium RC.

***Kindly tell me the webdriver equivalent for below errors --***

IDE Code :

```
<tr>
<td>deleteAllVisibleCookies</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>/index.html</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>selectFrame</td>
<td>content</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>select</td>
<td>librarySelect</td>
<td>label=XYZ Software Inc.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>userNameInput</td>
<td>demoUser</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>passwordInput</td>
<td>demoPassword</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>submitButton</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
.......
<tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=Admin</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
.......
```

**Exported Webdriver Code: [Contains Error]**

```
@Test
public void testArchivalLogReport() throws Exception {
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [deleteAllVisibleCookies |  | ]]
driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.html");
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | content | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | relative=up | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | menu | ]]
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin")).click();
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | relative=up | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | content | ]]
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[11]/span/b")).click();
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=content | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | name=content | ]]
// Warning: verifyTextPresent may require manual changes
try {
  assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Data Extract[\\s\\S]*$"));
} catch (Error e) {
  verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | relative=up | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | menu | ]]
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/font")).click();
}
```

Exported RC Code is Fine and looks like :

```
@Test
public void testArchival Log Report() throws Exception {
    selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies();
    selenium.open("/index.html");
    selenium.selectFrame("content");
    selenium.select("librarySelect", "label=XYZ Software Inc.");
    selenium.type("userNameInput", "demoUser");
    selenium.type("passwordInput", "demoPassword");
    selenium.click("submitButton");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");
    selenium.selectFrame("menu");
    selenium.click("link=Admin");
..........
 }
```

**How I am Exporting ?** 
I am using Java/ Junit 4/ Webdriver

I can see *Java/ Junit 4/ Webdriver Backed*   in option, **Should I go with that ??** it gives me the same exported file as in Selenium RC option, only change is how we get webdriver.

Comment: Was your `IDE` script built using some plugins?

Comment: @MarkRowlands : No I built it manually.

Comment: The errors you're seeing are most likely due to them having a similar but no direct switch to `Webdriver`. Your frame change for example, would be expressed as `driver.switchTo().frame()` where you pass in an element or an index. The way you're exporting shouldn't matter - you'll just have to use the `Webdriver` api, which is fully documented, to fill in the blanks - ie, where you have those commented errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using Webdriver API :

```
 @Test
 public void testArchivalLogReport()
    throws Exception
 {

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.html");
    driver.switchTo().frame("content");
    Select library = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("librarySelect")));
    library.selectByVisibleText("XYZ Software Inc.");
    driver.findElement(By.name("userInput")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("passwordInput")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submitButton")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
        .linkText("Admin")));

    // Store the window handle of the parent window, so that you can switch
    // back to it later.
    String wHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("XYZ")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[11]/span/b")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("someLink")).click();

    try
    {
        assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText()
            .matches("^[\\s\\S]*Data Extract[\\s\\S]*$"));
    }
    catch (Error e)
    {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    // Switch back to parent window using stored window handle
    driver.switchTo().window(wHandle);
    driver.switchTo().frame("menu");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/font")).click();

}
```